# How does SVM work?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, svm

Is it possible to provide a high-level, but specific explanation of how SVM algorithms work?
By high-level I mean it does not need to dig into the specifics of all the different types of SVM, parameters, none of that. By specific I mean an answer that explains the algebra, versus solely a geometric  interpretation.
I understand it will find a decision boundary that separates the data points from your training set into two pre-labeled categories. I also understand it will seek to do so by finding the widest possible gap between the categories and drawing the separation boundary through it. What I would like to know is how it makes that determination. I am not looking for code, rather an explanation of the calculations performed and the logic. 
I know it has something to do with orthogonality, but the specific steps are very "fuzzy" everywhere I could find an explanation.

Comment: Not a good SO question.  I'd recommend reading "Intro to Statistical Learning" by Hastie, Tibshirani, et al.

Comment: There are at least 10 (i just picked a number) very different optimization/calculation approaches. And even when picking one, it's hard to answer this with all these constraints (on what you don't want to hear).

Comment: @sascha I was thinking there could be an answer that describes them in general. I didn't realize there are a multitude of fundamentally different approaches. I though I could get an answer like "a Newton method starts with an arbitrary x, finds the zero for the linear approximation at that point x, and repeats the process recursively." Of course when discussing SVMs the explanation would be longer and more complicated.

Comment: I will edit to make it more clear, I am not necessarily against seeing a geometrical interpretation, but I would like the algebra as well, even if it is written in natural language and described at a high level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9_DJ4KvyYoo) that covers one seminal algorithm quite nicely.  The big revelations for me are (1) optimize the *square* of the critical metric, giving us a value that's always positive, so that minimizing the square (still easily differentiable) gives us the optimum; (2) Using a simple, but not-quite-obvious "kernel trick" to make the vector classifications compute easily.

Watch carefully at how unwanted terms disappear, leaving N+1 vectors to define the gap space in N dimensions.

Comment: Thank you. [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1NxnPkZM9bc) also explains it well.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a very small details that will help you to continue understanding how SVM works.

make everything simple, 2 dimensions and linearly seperable data. The general idea in SVM is to find a hyperplan that maximize the margine between two classes. each of your data is a vector from the center. One you suggest a hyperplan, you project you data vector into the vector defining the hyperplan and then you see if the length of you projected vector is before or after the hyperplan and this is how you define your two classes.

This is very simple way of seeing it, and then you can go into more details by following some papers or videos.

Comment: This is very helpful. Do you mean that is how you find one hiperplan that separates the data in two classes, then use that information to find the two points that are closes to each other and not in the same class? Is that right? Once you find those points, I get it, you can define a hiperplan by fidind a base where all the vectors are orthogonal to the difference between the two points. My problem was I didn't get how you separate them in the first place. That is what you told me, right?

Comment: to find and to describe the hyperplane you define the vector which is orthogonal to it from the center. you define it based on the maximum margine between the class. you can find more details by literature. then for any new poing"vector" you project it on the this vector defined the hyperplane  and you measure the length compared to the vector which tells you to which class it belong. this i very simple intuition and you need to read more to understand the algorithm behind it.